# use compareto( ) in read from file and save it in double linked list

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, inverted-index

i read word  from file and  a put it in double linked list  i was use  .equals() method to check  if the word is in double linked list  and the method was work fine  but when i use the  compareto() method  to sort the words   it's show   these exception :-

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at DoubleLinkedList.insert(DoubleLinkedList.java:49)
    at FileSystemIndexer.indexFile(FileSystemIndexer.java:88)
    at FileSystemIndexer.IndexDirectory(FileSystemIndexer.java:18)
    at TestPhase1.main(TestPhase1.java:15)
```

the method :-

```
  import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;



public class FileSystemIndexer {

    private  DoubleLinkedList<Index> invertedIndex;

    public  FileSystemIndexer (){
        invertedIndex=new DoubleLinkedList<Index>();
    }

    public void IndexDirectory(File dir){

         File[] files =dir.listFiles();
         for(int i=0 ; i<files.length; i++){
             indexFile(files[i]);    //FileSystemIndexer.java:18
         }

    }

    public void indexFile(File file ){
        Scanner input = null;
        try{
            input = new Scanner(file);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

            String c;
            input.useDelimiter(",|\\.|:|\\s+");
        while(input.hasNext()) {
        c=input.next();
        if(c.equals("")){
            c=input.next();


        }else{
        //System.out.println("here: " + c);

         if(invertedIndex.empty()){

        invertedIndex.insert( new Index(c,file));
         }else{
             invertedIndex.FindFirst();
             while(!invertedIndex.last()){

                 if(invertedIndex.retrieve().getWord().compareTo(c)==-1){
                     System.out.println("here: " + c);
                     invertedIndex.FindPrevious();
                     invertedIndex.insert(new Index(c,file));
                 }else if(invertedIndex.retrieve().getWord().compareTo(c)==1){
                     System.out.println("here: " + c);
                     invertedIndex.findNext();  
            invertedIndex.insert(new Index(c,file));  //FileSystemIndexer.java:88
                 }
                     else if(invertedIndex.retrieve().getWord().compareTo(c)==0){ 
                         System.out.println("here: " + c);
                         invertedIndex.retrieve().getFiles().insert(file);
                     }

                 /*
                 if(invertedIndex.retrieve().getWord().equals(c)){
                     invertedIndex.retrieve().getFiles().insert(file);

                 }

                 invertedIndex.findNext();
             } 
             if(invertedIndex.retrieve().getWord().equals(c)){
                 invertedIndex.retrieve().getFiles().insert(file);

             }else {
                 Index i=new Index(c,file);
                 invertedIndex.insert(i);
             }

         }/**/


        }                       if(invertedIndex.retrieve().getWord().compareTo(c)==-1){
             invertedIndex.FindPrevious();
             invertedIndex.insert(new Index(c,file)); 
         }else if(invertedIndex.retrieve().getWord().compareTo(c)==1){
             invertedIndex.findNext();
             invertedIndex.insert(new Index(c,file));
         }
             else if(invertedIndex.retrieve().getWord().compareTo(c)==0){ 
                 invertedIndex.retrieve().getFiles().insert(file);
             }


                }
            }
        }
        input.close();

       //}
        //catch (Exception e){
            //  System.out.println(e);
            //}



        }
```

the insert method in double Linked list :-

```
public void insert(T val ){
        Node<T> tmp= new Node<T> (val);  
        if(empty()){
            current=head=tmp;
        }else{
            tmp.next=current.next; //DoubleLinkedList.java:49
            tmp.previous=current;
            if(current.next !=null)
                current.next.previous=tmp;
            current.next=tmp;
            current=tmp;
        }
    }
```

my implementation for double linked list :

```
 public class DoubleLinkedList<T> {
    private Node<T> head;
    private Node<T> current ;

    public DoubleLinkedList(){
        head=current=null;
    }
    public boolean empty(){
        return head==null;

    }
    public boolean last(){
        return current.next==null;

    }
    public boolean first(){
        return current.previous==null;
    }

    public boolean full(){
         return false ;
    }
    public void FindFirst(){
        current=head;
    }
    public void findNext(){
        current=current.next;
    }
    public void FindPrevious(){
        current=current.previous;
    }
    public T retrieve(){
        return current.data;

    }



    public void update(T val ){
        current.data=val;
    }

    public void insert(T val ){
        Node<T> tmp= new Node<T> (val);  
        if(empty()){
            current=head=tmp;
        }else{
            tmp.next=current.next;
            tmp.previous=current;
            if(current.next !=null)
                current.next.previous=tmp;
            current.next=tmp;
            current=tmp;
        }/*
           if(empty()){
                current=head=tmp;
            }else{
                tmp.previous = current;
                tmp.next = current.next;
                if(current.next != null)
                    current.next.previous = tmp;
                current.next = tmp;
            }*/
        }


    public void remove(){
        if(current==head){
            head=head.next;
            if(head!=null)
                head.previous=null;
        }else{
            current.previous.next=current.next;
            if(current.next !=null)
                current.next.previous=current.previous;
        }

        if(current.next==null)
            current=head;
        else
                current=current.next ;
    }

    public void remove2(){

        if(current==head)
            head=head.next;
        else
            current.previous.next=current.next;

        if(current.next !=null)
            current.next.previous=current.previous;
        if(current.next==null)
            current=head;
        else
            current=current.next;

    }

}
```

Comment: Please show the declaration for Index, including its compareTo method.

Answer (score 0):

If your intention for insert is to add a new node at the end of the list then insertion code must be changes as following...

```
    public void insert(T val ){
        Node<T> tmp= new Node<T> (val);  
        if(empty()){
            current=head=tmp;
        }else{
            tmp.previous=current;
            current.next=tmp;
            current=tmp;
        }
    }
```

But if you want to insert Val somewhere in the middle then your code is fine, but you can not make set your current to tmp. So last line must be removed from your code.

```
    public void insert(T val ){
        Node<T> tmp= new Node<T> (val);  
        if(empty()){
            current=head=tmp;
        }else{
            tmp.previous = current;
            tmp.next = current.next;
            if(current.next != null)
                current.next.previous = tmp;
            current.next = tmp
        }
    }
```

If it does not work, then you must provide your implementation of DoubleLinkedList, else it would not be possible to provide any solution.

Comment: i wrote your method but it's gave exception  i put the implementation of DoubleLinkedList

Comment: Could you tell me the purpose of your insert?

Comment: i make inverted index for words and put in doubleLinkedList and   sort it in order

Comment: I think you need to get rid of your current. It is causing all the issues. You must use head to reach to the X element of the list and perform appropriate operations.

Comment: it's for my project   i can't change any thing  in implementation of double linked list